# Ruby on rails activerecord joins - select fields from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join

models:

```
#StatusMessage model
class StatusMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  default_scope :order => "created_at DESC"
end


#User Model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :status_messages 
end
```

In controller I want to join these two tables and get fields from both table. for example I want `email` field from `User` and `status` field from `StatusMessage`. When I use :

```
@status = User.joins(:status_messages)
```

Or

```
@status = User.includes(:status_messages)
```

It gives me only the user table data.

How can I implement this requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `includes` here. It preloads data so you won't have another SQL query when you do `@user.status_messages`.

And yes you can't really see the effect: you need to check your logs.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think it is possible (and reasonable) what you want to do. The reason for that is that the relation between `User` and `StatusMessage` is 1:n, that means that each user could have 0 to n status messages. How should these multitudes of attributes be included in your user model?

I think that the method `joints` in class ActiceRecord has a different meaning, it is part of the [query interface](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface). See the question [LEFT OUTER joins in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3)

There are similar questions on the net, here is what I have found that matches most:

- [Ruby on Rails: How to join two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764538/ruby-on-rails-how-to-join-two-tables): Includes (translated for your example) in the user a primary_status_message, which is then materialized in the query for the user. But it is held in one attribute, and to access the attributes of the status_message, you have to do something like that: `@user.primary_status_message.status`

Answer (score 1):

When you use @status = User.includes(:status_messages) then rails eagerley loads the data of all the tables.

My point is when you use this User.includes(:status_messages) it will loads the data of status_messages also but shows only users table data then if you want first user status_messages then you have to @user.first.status_messages