# How to add conditional where clauses in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, rails-activerecord

I am a rails newbie and am trying to perform a search on a table with rails, and i'm just using my sql knowledge to do this. But this just doesn't seems like rails or ruby even...

Is there any better way to do what i'm doing below? (basically, only pass date arguments to sql if they are filled)

```
def search(begin_date=nil, end_date=nil)

    subject = " and created_at "

    if !(begin_date.nil? || end_date.nil?)
      where_part = subject + "BETWEEN :begin_date AND :end_date"
    else if (begin_date.nil? && end_date.nil?) 
      where_part = ""
    else if(begin_date.nil?)
      where_part = subject + " <= :end_date"
    else if (end_date.nil?)
      where_part = subject + " >= :begin_date"
    end
    end
    end
    end

    User.joins(places: {containers: {label: :user}}).where("users.id= :user_id "+where_part, user_id: self.id, begin_date:begin_date, end_date:end_date).group(...).select(...)
end
```

**EDIT**

user.rb

```
has_many :containers
has_many :user_places
has_many :places, through: :user_places
has_many :labels
```

place.rb

```
has_many :containers
has_many :user_places
has_many :users, through: :user_places
```

container.rb

```
belongs_to :label
belongs_to :place
belongs_to :user
```

label.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :containers
```

Basically, i want to get a count of the number of containers within a given user's labels or with a direct relationship, per location, and want to be able to filter it by begin and end dates.

Either of this dates may be nil, and so i would need to address this in my "query".

My question is : How can i do this the rails way? I took a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and perhaps i could use the except command here somewhere...but this relationship model just seems a bit complex to do this with ActiveRecord...how may I?, i really think i should use ActiveRecord, but how?

Thank you

Comment: [here is a good example of how to do joins with active record][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764538/ruby-on-rails-how-to-join-two-tables

Comment: Hi, my issue is not with the joins...I just didn't write them because they aren't relevant. My thing is with the conditional search parameters

Comment: @itsalltime - I think what Bob is trying to say is - why not use Active Record instead of writing straight-up SQL? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can apply multiple `where` calls to a query so you can build your base query:

```
query = User.joins(...)
            .group(...)
            .select(...)
            .where('users.id = :user_id', :user_id => self.id)
```

and then add another `where` call depending on your date interval:

```
if(begin_date && end_date)
  query = query.where(:created_at => begin_date .. end_date)
  # or where('created_at between :begin_date and :end_date', :begin_date => begin_date, :end_date => end_date)
elsif(begin_date)
  query = query.where('created_at >= :begin_date', :begin_date => begin_date)
elsif(end_date)
  query = query.where('created_at <= :end_date', :end_date => end_date)
end
```

Each `where` call adds another piece to your overall WHERE clause using AND so something like:

```
q = M.where(a).where(b).where(c)
```

is the same as saying `WHERE a AND b AND c`.

Comment: Hi, this answer is great. Thanks. It seems I can't use the begin_date .. end_date (and had to use blank? instead of nil), because i'm collecting the datetimes from text field and converting them locally. `if !begin_date.blank?
      begin_date = DateTime.strptime("#{begin_date} 00:00:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").to_datetime
    end` I ended up using your alternative suggestion : `or where('created_at between :begin_date and :end_date', :begin_date => begin_date, :end_date => end_date)`

Comment: @itsalltime: Using `begin_date .. end_date` should work if `begin_date` and `end_date` are real date objects but it seems like you actually have strings instead. I'd recommend converting them to date objects before using them so that you only have to worry about date format issues in one place.

Comment: Hi, I do convert them with the function posted above, but even so the begin_date .. end_date doesn't work, and that's why i had to go for the alternative

Comment: I guess it must have been some other error, since it seems ok now. My problem now is that the "created_at" is being applied to the users table, and i wanted it applied to containers... How might i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of a great reason why you would actually want to generate SQL in your code. Active record seems like a much more efficient solution for your needs, unless there is a reason why you cant use that.

[Link explaining how to join tables with active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764538/ruby-on-rails-how-to-join-two-tables)

Comment: I actually had some doubts on how to use joins, but i guess i found a way to address what i wanted as i posted in my edited answer. My thing is actually with conditional search parameters.

Comment: oh, for cases like this and stuff: http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2014/09/14/working-with-complex-sql-statements/