# Filtering a Backbone.js Collection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-routing, backbone.js-collections

So I can fetch a collection from the database and display it using this code:

```
var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
articles.fetch({
  success: function(articles){
  var view = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: articles});
  view.render();
  }

});
```

and it works just fine.

In my Rails models (switching to rails for a sec) I have a publication model and an article model. Each Publication has many articles and each article belongs to one publication. Also, each article has a publication_id column.

Back to Backbone. Now what I would like to do is, from Backbone, fetch my articles collection but only the articles that have a specified publication id. Here is what I have:

```
  articles_by_id: function(id){
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    articles.fetch({
      data: {publication_id: id},
      success: function(x){
        console.log(x);
      }
    });
  }
```

This is still getting me all of the articles and not the filtered version I am looking for.
For the moment I just want to print the data to the console to see if I am getting the proper data. I will deal with rendering views later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kyle mentioned, you need to make sure that your Rails "API" layer supports having a publication_id as a parameter.  You can do this either by modifying your `config/routes` file or by checking for the presence of `publication_id` in the Rails action.

For example, you probably have something like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

just change that to:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:publication_id]
      @articles = Article.where(:publication_id => params[:publication_id]).all
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
  end
end
```

This isn't idiomatic, usually you would just apply the `where`'s conditionally similar to ths answer here [How to add conditional where clauses in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689720/how-to-add-conditional-where-clauses-in-rails) but it'll work for this situation.

Comment: You guys were right! And you just helped me end a day-long rabbit hole:)

Answer (score 0):

Does your API allow for filtering? passing data options will simply add them to the request for example your request would look like this.

`http://www.yourdomain.com/articles?publication_id=id`

You can however fetch all of them and then filter your collection client side.

```
  articles_by_id: function(id){
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    articles.fetch({
      success: function(x){
        console.log(x.where({publication_id: id}));
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: How would I go about filtering collection from client side? I have been playing with the filter and where functions from the underscore library but no success yet. I could be using them incorrectly though. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2623706 the above snippet should `console.log` the filtered collection, change what attributes you pass to where based on how you want to filter the collection.