# Rails where clause with between not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following query in rails...

```
@registrations = Registration.where(Orientation.where(class_date: @start_date..@end_date))
```

The query itself does not throw an error, however if I try to inspect @registrations do anything with the variable I get the error...

```
Cannot visit ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689720/how-to-add-conditional-where-clauses-in-rails

Comment: can you provide the sql you want to be generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Orientation.where(class_date: @start_date..@end_date)`

does the range query you like

`SELECT * FROM orientations WHERE class_date BETWEEN <start_date> AND <end_date>`

**UPDATE**

```
Registration.where(created_at: @start_date..@end_date).
  joins(:orientation).
  where('orientations.created_at' => @start_date..@end_date)
```

will make the following `SQL` which I think is what you need

```
SELECT registrations.* FROM registrations INNER JOIN orientations ON orientations.id = registrations.orientation_id WHERE (registrations.created_at BETWEEN '2014-02-17 16:01:41' AND '2014-02-19 16:01:41') AND (orientations.created_at BETWEEN '2014-02-17 16:01:41' AND '2014-02-19 16:01:41')
```

Comment: This works for Orientations, but not registrations. The query Orientation.where(class_date: @start_date..@end_date) is valid, but the query  Registration.where(Orientation.where(class_date: @start_date..@end_date)). I get the error Cannot visit ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: Correct, Orientation has_many Registrations, and Registration belongs_to Orientation.

Comment: I updated my post to show the current error I am getting with my code.

Comment: Daym son...you nailed it! Thanks so much.